# Calculate payout from a bet depending on how much you put in, and everyone else.

Tags: probability

So basically, if there's two teams to bet on, and there's let's say 4 people that is going to bet, it might look like this:

```
Person 1: $256 on team 1.
Person 2: $171 on team 1.
Person 3: $23 on team 2.
Person 4: $74 on team 2.
```

So, let's say team 1 wins, and then we come to the point to calculate how much each person should get. How would I calculate the odds & how would I give person 1 more than person 2 as he bet a higher value, but everyone who bet should still get some amount, depending on the size. (a person who would have bet like $1 wouldn't have gotten anything at all)

Let me know if there's anything I need to explain better. Might have missed something out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll generalise so it will work for any number of teams and any number of bets. Below, I apply it to your example.

Let $B_{ij}$ be the dollar amount of the $j^{th}$ bet on Team $i$.

Then the Total Amount Bet is $\qquad T := \sum_{i=1}^\infty{\sum_{j=1}^\infty{B_{ij}}}$.

Of course, the upper bounds are not infinite. It just means summing over all bets/teams.

For a fixed Team $i$:

The Total Amount Bet on Team $i$ is $\qquad T_i := \sum_{j=1}^\infty{B_{ij}}$.

Then the Payout Per Dollar for any bet on Team $i$ is $\qquad P_i := \dfrac{T}{T_i}$.

This figure $P_i$ is the odds for the Team $i$ in a sense, being the amount you expect back if you win for each dollar you bet on it.

The Total Payout for the $j^{th}$ bet on Team $i$ is $\qquad P_{ij} := B_{ij} \times P_i$.

For your example:

$B_{11} = 256\qquad$
$B_{12} = 171\qquad$
$B_{21} = 23\qquad$
$B_{22} = 74\qquad$

$T = 256+171+23+74 = 524$

$T_1 = 256+171 = 427$

$T_2 = 23+74 = 97$

$P_1 = 524/427 = 1.227166$ (rounded to 6 decimal places)

$P_2 = 524/97 = 5.402062$ (rounded to 6 decimal places)

If Team $1$ wins:

$\qquad$ Person $1$ gets back $P_{11} = \$256 \times 1.227166 = \$314.15$

$\qquad$ Person $2$ gets back $P_{12} = \$171 \times 1.227166 = \$209.85$

If Team $2$ wins:

$\qquad$ Person $3$ gets back $P_{21} = \$23 \times 5.402062 = \$124.25$

$\qquad$ Person $4$ gets back $P_{22} = \$74 \times 5.402062 = \$399.75$

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Talk about getting confused. xD So many weird symbols, lol.

Comment: Simple version: Say Team $1$ wins. Total Pool is $\$524$. Divide that by the total bet on Team $1$, which is $\$427$. Now $\$524 / \$427 = 1.227166$. Person $1$ bet $\$256$ so multiply $\$256 \times 1.227166 = \$314.15$ is his winnings.

Comment: Thanks, can't vote up because I need 15 reputation but thanks!